# CSS Bootstrap Font Awesome 4.0.3 Header Referencing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
    @import url(http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css);
```

This is the tag I have imported into my CSS File For my website. The template I am using is currently referencing this import in this block of code below:

```
#header {
  background: #1731be;
}
@media (max-width: 979px) {
  #header {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
.brand {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 29px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.brand h1 {
 overflow: hidden;
}
.brand a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 94px;
  line-height: 66px;
}
.brand a:hover {
  color: #fff9cc;
}
.brand .fa-gamepad {   /*===Trouble area===*/
  margin-top: -11px;
}
@media (max-width: 979px) {
 .brand {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
 }
}
```

What I would like to do is edit the line of code that references **".brand .fa-gamepad,"** and use my own logo in the same directory rather than adding in artwork from the Font Awesome Library. Any suggestions on how to add this in and replace what is currently there? Thanks!

Comment: you can add the logo in html of yours

Comment: your /*===Trouble area===*/ shows the style you can customize it

Comment: Please post the related code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a working Snippet example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve